# How do I scroll to an element within an overflowed Div?

Tags: jquery

I have 20 list items inside of a div that can only show 5 at a time. What is a good way to scroll to item #10, and then item #20? I know the height of all the items.

The [scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plugin does this, but its source is not super easy to understand without really getting into it. **I don't want to use this plugin.**

Let's say I have a function that takes 2 elements `$parentDiv`, `$innerListItem`, neither `$innerListItem.offset().top` nor `$innerListItem.positon().top` gives me the correct scrollTop for $parentDiv.

Comment: Removed my answer due to your update.  But trust me, having had this same attitude before, there are lots of browser quirks with position and margins, etc...the plugin is a much simpler route and less time consuming, and only 3k **before** GZip.

Comment: Use the scrollTo plugin anyway.  It's not difficult.  `$("#container").scrollTo(target, duration, options)`.  Target is just an `#anchor`. Done.

Comment: it seems like there should be knowledge out there to do this without a plugin. tomorrow ill start reading the source

Comment: @mkoryak - The knowledge is out there, but when you account for the browser quirks, you basically end up with... **the .scrollTo plugin**, so why re-invent the wheel all the time?

Comment: @Nick - scrollTo does much more then what i require, so i can end up with the .scrollTo plugin that does exactly what i want if i read the source

Comment: IMHO, you'll probably end up with the exact subset of what you need out of .scrollTo *today*. But in a few months time, while .scrollTo has been updated to IE9, FF4 and Chrome 6, *you* will have to start over... 3k seems like a very low price to avoid this.

Comment: yeah i guess you have a point. I am writing my own plugin, and id rather not have any dependancies but it might be more trouble then its worth. granted scrollTo hasnt been updated in a while

Answer (score 247, accepted):

The `$innerListItem.position().top` is actually relative to the `.scrollTop()` of its first positioned ancestor. So the way to calculate the correct `$parentDiv.scrollTop()` value is to begin by making sure that `$parentDiv` is positioned. If it doesn't already have an explicit `position`, use `position: relative`. The elements `$innerListItem` and all its ancestors up to `$parentDiv` need to have no explicit position. Now you can scroll to the `$innerListItem` with:

```
// Scroll to the top
$parentDiv.scrollTop($parentDiv.scrollTop() + $innerListItem.position().top);

// Scroll to the center
$parentDiv.scrollTop($parentDiv.scrollTop() + $innerListItem.position().top
    - $parentDiv.height()/2 + $innerListItem.height()/2);
```

Answer (score 162):

This is my own plugin (will position the element in top of the the list. Specially for `overflow-y : auto`. May not work with `overflow-x`!):

**NOTE**: `elem` is the HTML selector of an element which the page will be scrolled to. Anything supported by jQuery, like: `#myid`, `div.myclass`, `$(jquery object)`, [dom object], etc.

```
jQuery.fn.scrollTo = function(elem, speed) { 
    $(this).animate({
        scrollTop:  $(this).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top + $(elem).offset().top 
    }, speed == undefined ? 1000 : speed); 
    return this; 
};
```

If you don't need it to be animated, then use:

```
jQuery.fn.scrollTo = function(elem) { 
    $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top + $(elem).offset().top); 
    return this; 
};
```

How to use:

```
$("#overflow_div").scrollTo("#innerItem");
$("#overflow_div").scrollTo("#innerItem", 2000); //custom animation speed
```

Note: `#innerItem` can be anywhere inside `#overflow_div`. It doesn't really have to be a direct child.

Tested in Firefox (23) and Chrome (28).

If you want to scroll the whole page, check [this question](/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element).

Comment: what is `elem` ?? you don't explain it at all.

Comment: You get better mileage/non conflict if you swap $ in the fn.scrollTo to jQuery instead

Comment: Big flaw with this, your not containing the scope: `$(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top + $(elem, $(this)).offset().top);` - regards

Comment: If you want to leave some top margin between the page and the element (which may look better in some cases), subtract, for example, 10px, like: `$(this).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top + $(elem).offset().top - 10`.

Comment: If you are having position differences between Firefox and Chrome (or other browsers), check your html code (see [this bug report](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13696))

Comment: Works nicely in IE11 too <3

Answer (score 36):

I've adjusted Glenn Moss' answer to account for the fact that overflow div might not be at the top of the page.

```
parentDiv.scrollTop(parentDiv.scrollTop() + (innerListItem.position().top - parentDiv.position().top) - (parentDiv.height()/2) + (innerListItem.height()/2)  )
```

I was using this on a google maps application with a responsive template.  On resolution > 800px, the list was on the left side of the map.  On resolution < 800 the list was below the map.

Answer (score 6):

The above answers will position the inner element at the top of the overflow element even if it's in view inside the overflow element. I didn't want that so I modified it to not change the scroll position if the element is in view.

```
jQuery.fn.scrollTo = function(elem, speed) {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var $this_top = $this.offset().top;
    var $this_bottom = $this_top + $this.height();
    var $elem = jQuery(elem);
    var $elem_top = $elem.offset().top;
    var $elem_bottom = $elem_top + $elem.height();

    if ($elem_top > $this_top && $elem_bottom < $this_bottom) {
        // in view so don't do anything
        return;
    }
    var new_scroll_top;
    if ($elem_top < $this_top) {
        new_scroll_top = {scrollTop: $this.scrollTop() - $this_top + $elem_top};
    } else {
        new_scroll_top = {scrollTop: $elem_bottom - $this_bottom + $this.scrollTop()};
    }
    $this.animate(new_scroll_top, speed === undefined ? 100 : speed);
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer only works with direct children of the scrollable element, while the other answers didn't centered the child in the scrollable element.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="scrollable-box">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 1
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 2
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 3
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 4
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 5
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 6
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 7
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 8
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 9
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 10
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 11
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 12
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 13
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 14
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 15
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-item">
            Child 16
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.scrollable-box {
    width: 800px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #444;
}
.scrollable-item {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Build a small jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.scrollDivToElement = function(childSel) {
    if (! this.length) return this;

    return this.each(function() {
        let parentEl = $(this);
        let childEl = parentEl.find(childSel);

        if (childEl.length > 0) {
            parentEl.scrollTop(
                parentEl.scrollTop() - parentEl.offset().top + childEl.offset().top - (parentEl.outerHeight() / 2) + (childEl.outerHeight() / 2)
            );
        }
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
$('.scrollable-box').scrollDivToElement('.scrollable-item:eq(12)');
```

**Explanation:**

1. `parentEl.scrollTop(...)` sets current vertical position of the scroll bar.
2. `parentEl.scrollTop()` gets the current vertical position of the scroll bar.
3. `parentEl.offset().top` gets the current coordinates of the **parentEl** relative to the document.
4. `childEl.offset().top` gets the current coordinates of the **childEl** relative to the document.
5. `parentEl.outerHeight() / 2` gets the outer height divided in half (because we want it centered) of the child element.
6. when used:

`$(parent).scrollDivToElement(child);`

The **parent** is the scrollable div and it can be a string or a jQuery object of the DOM element.
The **child** is any child that you want to scroll to and it can be a string or a jQuery object of the DOM element.

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/binarweb/pen/xxVEoVb)

Answer (score 3):

I write these 2 functions to make my life easier:

```
function scrollToTop(elem, parent, speed) {
    var scrollOffset = parent.scrollTop() + elem.offset().top;
    parent.animate({scrollTop:scrollOffset}, speed);
    // parent.scrollTop(scrollOffset, speed);
}

function scrollToCenter(elem, parent, speed) {
    var elOffset = elem.offset().top;
    var elHeight = elem.height();
    var parentViewTop = parent.offset().top;
    var parentHeight = parent.innerHeight();
    var offset;

    if (elHeight >= parentHeight) {
        offset = elOffset;
    } else {
        margin = (parentHeight - elHeight)/2;
        offset = elOffset - margin;
    }

    var scrollOffset = parent.scrollTop() + offset - parentViewTop;

    parent.animate({scrollTop:scrollOffset}, speed);
    // parent.scrollTop(scrollOffset, speed);
}
```

And use them:

```
scrollToTop($innerListItem, $parentDiv, 200);
// or
scrollToCenter($innerListItem, $parentDiv, 200);
```

Comment: `elem.offset().top` is calculating from the top of the screen. I want that calculate from the parent element. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it for a very long time, this is what I came up with:

```
    jQuery.fn.scrollTo = function (elem) {
        var b = $(elem);
        this.scrollTop(b.position().top + b.height() - this.height());
    };
```

and I call it like this

```
$("#basketListGridHolder").scrollTo('tr[data-uid="' + basketID + '"]');
```