# scroll to the vertical middle of a DIV

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

i have a onepage design with some divs together. when i click on menu link ("3") i want to scroll to div #3 and it should be in the vertical middle of the screen.

i tried:

```
$('#go').click(function() {
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(.box).offset().top - ( $(window).height() -
$(.box).outerHeight(true) ) / 2  }, 200);
});
```

it doesn't work. what did i forgot?

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/herrfischerhamburg/7CVtm/1/

Comment: If you check your console you should see you have errors in your script. It should be `$('.box')...` instead of `$(.box)`.

Comment: Overflowed div, scroll to any contained element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346011/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-within-an-overflowed-div  With minor modification, instead of scrolling to an element you could grab the total height and divide by 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your selectors in quotes: `$('.box')`

```
$('#go').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $box = $('.box').eq(2); // select the third box

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $box.offset().top - ($(window).height() - $box.outerHeight(true)) / 2
    }, 200);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7CVtm/2/)

Comment: awesome! and when i have a menu and i want to targt every DIV with a link? now it works only with #3. sorry, i think my question was not precise enough ... . many thx anyway :)

Comment: No problem, you just need to change the value in the `eq` function to target the required div.

Comment: hmm, now he wants the "active" menu to be styled. any idea how to build this "scroll to middle" function into this? -> http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/ i tried but i don't get it, think it' too much for me as a jquery novice ...

Comment: now i have this:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/herrfischerhamburg/7CVtm/7/).
and some questions:
- how to make the script "smarter"? i thinks it's too big.
- how to make that only the most top DIV makes the related menu link active (green)?

Comment: You can use data attributes to tidy that code up massively. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/7CVtm/9/

Comment: this looks MUCH better, but when i give the DIVs a height of 700px (so that there is only one DIV visible at a time) than the active menu won't change colour anymore ... :-/

Comment: okay it checks if the whole ".box" div is visible, but i have to chek if the "anchor" inside the ".box" div is visible. or i have to check if the TOP of a ".box" is visible and then add some pixels like "+50" ore something ...

Comment: That's just a logic change in the `isElementVisible` function: http://jsfiddle.net/7CVtm/10/

Comment: hmmm ... i think i need more of a "scrollspy" to check if a DIV is in height of the menu.

Comment: @McCrossan: many thanks for your help! i made it with your code and added twitter bootstrap scrollspy. one question: how to get bootstrap scrollspy working in jsfiddle? [link]http://jsfiddle.net/herrfischerhamburg/cD6aw/  ... i don't know how to add "data-spy="scroll" data-offset="200" data-target="#myScrollspy"" to the body ... ( i tried "fiddle options ...).