# How to make scrollbar go down when adding new LI elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having issues when I'm creating dynamic LI.

They're added, but the scrollbar goes up, instead of down. See image bellow [image]

I'm adding all content with javascript. So i'm not sure what do add for making the scrollbar go down. Any idea?

This is the demo: http://jsbin.com/qonuy/1/

```
$('#btPre').click(function(e) {
    var list = $('#myTab');
    var listActive = $('#myTab .active');
    addNewElement(list,listActive);
});

var addNewElement = function addNewElement(list,listActive){
    var psize= list.find('li');
    listActive.removeClass('active');
    psize = psize.size()-1;
    var newLi='<li class="active" id='+psize+'>';
    newLi=newLi+'<a href="#tab_preview" data-toggle="pill">';
    newLi=newLi+'<span  class="display edit_text">Card '+psize+'</span>';
    newLi=newLi+'<input type="text" class="edit" style="display:none"/></a></li>';
    list.append(newLi);
    $('#myTab a[href="#tab_preview"]').tab('show');
};
```

Comment: have a look at this - essentially you want to scroll to a position in your div after adding an element - or scroll your div to the position of your last element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346011/jquery-scroll-to-an-element-within-an-overflowed-div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the following to the bottom of your addNewElement function. Worked in the jsBin, anyway.

```
$("#myTab").scrollTop($("#myTab")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Comment: Your answer is right....here is the same test: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/m5Le101z/